# jquery fixed div on scroll, smooth movement

Tags: php, jquery, css

**Edit: See the answer below, latest version with z-index and stuff is at http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/6/**
It has a small bug when scrolling back to top where the first sidebar dont stop after reaching its starting position, quick fix in the fiddle was to set the .fixed top:XXpx; to more than the height of the header.

Thanks for the help, Fbynite!

i have a jquery script that i need to fix,
I have very little knowledge of javascript and a guy made this for me,
 
it does what i want it to, 
it starts to follow when you scroll and then stops as it hits the next sidebar and then the next bar starts to follow as you continue scrolling.
 
But the movement of the sidebar's is very jumpy and glitchy and i have no idea what to do.
An example of something i'm looking for is the small bar you can see in every post on http://9gag.com, the one containing the title, rating and twitter/facebook sharing.
If you're good with jquery please take a shot at it..
i have this fiddle to clear it out alittle: jsfiddle.net/7KcJb/4 
(same as the one on 9gag mine is just floated and moved out of the post with some margin-left: -XXpx;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      $('.socialbookmarks2').each(function(){
          var top = $(this).offset().top - parseFloat($(this).css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
          var bottom = (top + $(this).parent().height());
        if (y >= top && y < bottom) {
          $(this).addClass('fixed');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('fixed');
        }
      });  
  });
});
```

If you can fix the script or have another one that works smooth for this i'd be extremely happy!
I am open minded to animated movement or other effects as long as its smooth and not jumpy as now.
Thank you!

Comment: what technology you are using .net or PHP???

Comment: oh sorry i forgot, php

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's glitchy/jumpy is because your removing the class everytime you scroll. Try this:

```
$('.socialbookmarks2').each(function(){
  var top = $(this).offset().top - parseFloat($(this).css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  var bottom = (top + $(this).parent().height());
  if (y >= top && y < bottom) {
    $('.socialbookmarks2').removeClass('fixed');
    $(this).addClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

You could also change the comparison in the y values to make the div transition a bit more seamless. But I will let you play with that. Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/2/.

Example:

```
if ( (y+30) >= top && y < bottom)
```

Comment: Okay, i have been messing around with it and its nice and smooth now! thanks for that!
But i cant seem to figure out how to make the floating bar stop before its bottom hits the top of the next bar, so they overlay each other right now, any idea how to fix that?
http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/3/ is what i have right now, looks much better than before

Comment: @user2267175 Are you trying to have it stop and remain visible? Or you just want the other one to show before they begin to overlap?

Comment: if it can remain visible, but stop 20px before the bottom of one bar hits the top of the next bar, it would be ace

Comment: Nevermind about the comment above..
I have added z-index 1 / 2 so the top bar slides under the one below as you scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/6/
 now i'm just having a small issue with when you scroll back up, it dont stop at where it started, it continues up into the header, as a quick fix i increased the top:XXpx; so its always lower than the header..

Answer (score 0):

you can make it smoother with a first lookup with `var elm=$(this);` and changing all following `$(this)` inside the same scope like `var top = elm.offset().top - parseFloat(elm.css(...`
until now you code has to refind and to refind what `$(this)` is